# Select all combinations of values in a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

Let's say I have a vector like this:

```
test<-c("a","b","c")
```

I am trying to return a list with all possible combinations of the elements of the vector where order does not matter and "a" is always in the output to get something like this:

```
[[1]]
  [1] "a"
  [2] "b"
  [3] "c"
[[2]]
  [1] "a"
  [2] "b"
[[3]]
  [1] "a"
  [2] "c"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `lapply(rev(seq_along(test)), function(i) combn(test, i, FUN = function(x) if('a' %in% x) x else NA))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several packages that have powerset functions (rje, ggm, HapEstXXR).  Of these HapEstXXR uses C/C++ so it should be particularly fast:

```
library(HapEstXXR)
lapply(powerset(c("b", "c")), function(x) c("a", x))
```

giving:

```
4 sets to create.
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[2]]
[1] "a" "c"

[[3]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this without manually specifying the vector elements?

Comment: `powerset(test[-1])` or `powerset(setdiff(test, "a"))`